# Using case statement or IF inside a WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have several stored procedures that are almost identical but have some different AND parts inside a WHERE clause.

Based on a variable `deptname`, I want to add additional AND/OR conditions to my already existing WHERE clause. So kind of like IF/CASE WHEN on the part that is different.

Think about it as string concatenation

```
query_string = 'WHERE a= XYZ AND B= 123"
if deptname = a:  query_string + "AND additional conditions for dept a"
else if deptname = b:query_string + "AND additional conditions for dept b"
```

What is the appropriate way to use a variable?

here is some pseudo code of what I am trying to do

```
SELECT 
personID AS pid,
personcode,
persondeptcode,
more_fields AS fields
FROM
TABLE_XYZ
WHERE
--shared parts
personcode = 'C' 
AND
persondeptcode = 'MAJ'
--- NOW the different part
IF @deptname = "deptA"
AND 
(
PROGRAM_LDESCR IN 
(
    'prog1',
    'prog2',
    'prog3'
)
OR
aprogram IN ('aprogram1') 
OR 
(aprogram IN ('aprogram2') AND PLAN_LDESCR IN ('plan123'))
); 
--- THIS IS A DIFFERENT DEPT SO WE HAVE DIFFERENT AND PART 
ELSE IF @deptname = "deptB"

(
PROGRAM_LDESCR IN 
(
    '1234'
)
OR
aprogram IN ('a1234') 
);
```

Comment: Generally, `IF condition THEN conditionA ELSE conditionB END` can be written as `(condition AND conditionA) or (not(condition) and conditionB)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression in this case, the important thing is to make sure you have an `ELSE` clause to ensure the expression remains true if `@deptname` is *not* one of the two values with extra conditions:

```
WHERE personcode = 'C' 
  AND persondeptcode = 'MAJ'
  AND (CASE @deptname 
       WHEN "deptA" THEN PROGRAM_LDESCR IN ('prog1', 'prog2', 'prog3')
                      OR aprogram IN ('aprogram1') 
                      OR aprogram IN ('aprogram2') AND PLAN_LDESCR IN ('plan123')
       WHEN "deptB" THEN PROGRAM_LDESCR IN ('1234')
                      OR aprogram IN ('a1234')
       ELSE 1
       END)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=313467bea4fb3a23386f0d401de51c45) is a simple demo of a `CASE` expression used in this fashion.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want something like:

```
AND
(@deptname = 'dept123' AND (PROGRAM_LDESCR IN ('1234') OR aprogram IN ('a1234')) OR
 @deptname <> 'dept123'
)
```

Comment: I guess my question was not clear and I need to edit it

Answer (score 1):

To combine the last part of the `WHERE` clause (if I'm understanding your commented-code correctly), you could do something like the following:

```
SELECT 
    personID AS pid,
    personcode,
    persondeptcode,
    more_fields AS fields
FROM
    TABLE_XYZ
WHERE
    personcode = 'C' 
    AND persondeptcode = 'MAJ'
    AND (
        (@deptname="deptA" AND (PROGRAM_LDESCR IN ('prog1', 'prog2', 'prog3') OR aprogram IN ('aprogram1') OR (aprogram IN ('aprogram2') AND PLAN_LDESCR IN ('plan123'))))
        OR
        (@deptname="deptB" AND (PROGRAM_LDESCR IN ('1234') OR aprogram IN ('a1234'))
    )
```

Normally you would use the `WHERE` clause to filter out unnecessary rows of data and a `CASE` statement if you wanted to actually change the value in the `SELECT` statement (I rarely see `CASE` statements outside a `SELECT` clause, unless it is doing something like a complex sort).

Comment: No there was a typo. Edited the question

Comment: yes, the idea is to have different WHERE based on the dept value

Comment: @Quantico oh I see, got it. Glad you were able to find the solution to this!